# How can I send a notification every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I want my website to send a notification every 10 seconds. I use this java code because must work in mobile chrome:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
 if (result === 'granted') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
   registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker');
  });
 }
});
```

What code should I add? I tried to add;

```
function callOnLoad(){
setInterval('',10000);
```

but I could not.

Comment: Check the documentation of setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
You are making it do nothing every 10 seconds. replace `''` with the name of the method or the code you want to call.

Comment: i try but didn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do every 10 seconds? Request the permission until it is granted? Or show a new notification every 10 seconds?

Comment: I want  to send a notification every 10 seconds when notification result  granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `showNotification` every 10 seconds, put it inside a `setInterval`:

```
var myInterval;
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
 if (result === 'granted') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
   myInterval = setInterval(function () {
     registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker')
   }, 10000);
  });
 }
});
```

`setInterval()` returns an interval ID that can be used to stop the interval with `clearInterval(myInterval)`.

Comment: Thank you! The code works but only sends one notification after allowing it. Don't work setInterval.

Comment: oh, my bad. You need to wrap setInterval in a function. If you do it in a lambda function like I did, you need to declare the `myInterval` variable outside, so you are able to clear the interval if you want to. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.